# How to read lines of input from server? (java client console application)

Tags: java, sockets, client, inputstream

I've connected to an already existent server that contains lines of strings I need to read in. Given that I only need to read in a String type, which input reader would work here so I could read line by line in my While loop? Here's my simple Client:

```
public class Client
{
public static final int PORT_NUMBER = 8888;


public static void main(String[] args)
{
 int port = PORT_NUMBER;
 String content;
 OutputStream output;
 InputStream input;
 Socket s = null;

try
{
 s = new Socket("server.example.exp", port);
 output = s.getOutputStream();
 input = s.getInputStream();

 System.out.println("Connected to " + s.getInetAddress() + " on port " + s.getPort());
}
catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}

while (true)
{
 try
 {
  //read next line from server
 }
 catch (EOFException eof){
  System.out.println("eof encountered" + eof.getMessage());
  break;
 }
 catch (OptionalDataException ode){System.out.println("OptionalDataException" + ode.getMessage());}
 catch (IOException ioe){System.out.println("IOException on read object");}
 catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf){System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException");}
}


  }
}
```

I know it's a very basic question, I'm just having trouble getting started, is all. I appreciate any clarification. Thanks.

Comment: You've gotten the required `InputStream`, although there is no guarantee that it's valid upon entering the while loop. So what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I know it lacks validation at the moment. Just a skeleton to learn on.

My question is how can I work with that InputStream object in order to readNextLine? The methods available -- like read() -- only return int.

Comment: Start by taking a look through [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [All about sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from an InputStream, you can wrap it in a [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), and then a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), from which you can readLine:

```
BufferedReader input;
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

Then:
while(true){
    try{
        input.readLine();//Read from server
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the folloWing line before your while

```
 BufferedReader inp2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
 while (true) {
    try {  
       inp2.readLine();
    }
 }
```